# Determine element position in list

Tags: csh

Consider a list of exam scores (give as percentages) such that

```
set list = ( 90 100 80 )
```

The position of these scores in the list determine which exam they pertain to.  For example, the first element, `90`, corresponds to Exam 1, the second element, `100`, corresponds to Exam 2, etc.).

I sort `list` to find the minimum score as follows:

```
echo $list | fmt -1 | sort -n | head -1
```

Clearly the minimum score in this case would be `80` which is the third element in the list (corresponding to the third exam).  I need to know how to determine the minimum value **as well as its corresponding position in a list** of arbitrary length.  In this way I can retrieve the proper 'total possible points' for that exam and apply a drop grade.

Comment: what if your data is like `set list = ( 80 100 80 )`. How do you expect to handle "tie" duplicate low values? AND, do you really have to do this in `csh`? If so, the only solution I can think of is to use duplicate arrays, and then iterate thru the "position" list, comparing values, and then returning the index of the position. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter The first instance would be dropped in this case for simplicity.  The criteria for 'lowest exam grade' only depends upon the percentage scored, not raw scores/points for a weighted grading system.

Comment: @shellter I've done exactly that.  I was hoping for a more elegant way of doing this but csh is inherently a poor choice.  The list doesn't grow beyond four elements so the code isn't prohibitively cumbersome.

Comment: I don't see away around something awkard;-).. Either pass the whole array into `awk` and have it search for lowest value and return index, or as above, parallel arrays. The `awk` approach would automatically keep track of it's limits via the `NF` (or `NR`) variables. AND, I don't has a csh to test with, so I'm just offering ideas. Good luck.